# Count multiple occurrences and write sums to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Using SQL, what is the best way to retrieve the count of multiple recurring items in `table1`, and put the sums in `table2`?

Table2 is the result I desire

[image: table2 is the result i desire]

as text :

```
table1
+----------+
|  name    | 
+----------+
| john doe |
+----------+
|mary smith| 
+----------+
| john doe |
+----------+
|mary smith|     
+----------+
| john doe |
+----------+


table2
+----------+-------+
|  name    | count |
+----------+-------+
| john doe |     3 |
+----------+-------+
|mary smith|     2 |
+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server use:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as count_all
INTO table2
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

For Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
AS
SELECT name, count(*) as count_all
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `CTAS( Create Table AS )` syntax containing aggregation(*originally question had no DB tag*):

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 AS
SELECT name, count(*) as "count"
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY name
```

**But If** `SQL Server` is the case, then use:

```
SELECT name, count(*) as "count"
  INTO Table2
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY name
```

to create a new table.

**or** no need to produce a new table, just record as the aggregation query through creating a view:

```
CREATE VIEW View1 AS
SELECT name, count(*) as "count"
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY name
```

which I suggest rather than creating a new table.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9f98d427cb53183c7ca7559a491993f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much for that fast reply!  The statement achieves the desired result, but throws an error on the SELECT unless i comment out the first line. I should have clarified that I'm using SQL Server, and perhaps CTAS is not compatible?